# How to "flat" git history after merge

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-rebase

First of all, I'm sorry for the title. I don't know to describe the issue without a sample.

**1. And here is my issues:**

I have got a history like this :

```
C1-->C2-->C3-->C4-->C8  --> develop
     |         |
     C5-->C6-->C7      --> feature (this branch was deleted after merge)
```

This kind of history is difficult to take control.

I know that this history appeared because I merge `feature` into `develop` without `git rebase` first.

But, Is there anyway to re-write the above history to new history like this:

> C1-->C2-->C3-->C4-->**C5-->C6-->C7**-->C8

**2. This is my way to solve the issue:**

***[Idea]:*** There are 4 group of commit:

- (C5, C6, C7) from `feature` branch
- (C2, C3) from `develop` branch
- (C4) is a commit for merge
- (C8) is new commit after merge

So, split all commit group into new branchs=> then merge back again with `git rebase`.

***Step 1:*** split all commit C5, C6, C7 into a new branch ( and merge it back later)

```
git checkout develop
git checkout C7
git checkout -b staging1
```

And the history of `staging1`

> C1-->C2-->**C5-->C6-->C7**   --> staging1

***Step 2:*** rebase `develop` branch to remove merged feature.

```
git checkout develop
git rebase HEAD~2
```

And the history of `develop` became

> C1-->C2-->C3'-->C8'  --> develop

***Step 3 :*** Split commit C8' into a new branch

```
git checkout develop
git checkout -b staging2
```

***Step 4 :*** Reset `develop` branch to C3'

```
git checkout develop
git reset --hard C3'
```

And the history of `develop` became

> C1-->C2-->C3'  --> develop

**Step 5** merge `staging1` to `develop`

Rebase first

```
git checkout staging1
git rebase develop staging1
```

Then merge

```
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff staging1
```

History of `develop` became:

> C1-->C2-->C3'-->**C5'-->C6'-->C7'**

**Step 6**  merge `staging2` to `develop`
Rebase first
    git checkout staging2
    git rebase develop staging2

Then merge
    git checkout develop
    git merge --no-ff staging2
History of `develop` became:

> C1-->C2-->C3'-->**C5'-->C6'-->C7'**->C8''

---

But C4 (merge commit) was lost. (It will take me more effort to merge again carefully).
And my approach look so complex, easy to make a mistake.

So, my question is :

#### Is there a better way to "flat" my history

Comment: `This kind of history is difficult to take control.` — why?

Comment: @AlexeyTen because history will be messed up. Reading a `flat history` vs  `history tree`. I think `flat history` `much more readable`. Especially when you are working with too much branch in your repository. And `manipulate a commit is more easy` (`For example`: I want reword my commit msg of C6, It would be easier in `flat history version`) if you working with `flat history`

Comment: Have you checked `git log --help`? Especially `--topo-order` and `--graph` keys.

Comment: @AlexeyTen thank your for great info.Actually, I use `git history visualizer` more frequent than `--graph` command.  Back to the topic, `--topo-order` will help me read logs more easier but It might not helpful if I want  to `merge` or `rebase`(For example: I want to reword commit msg in C6)

Comment: `git rebase` has `--preserve-merges` option. And it's not a good idea to change commits after they are merged

Comment: Thanks you , I will test that options. I agree that It's not a good idea to change commit after they are merged. I always avoid to rewrite history, and asked my team to be careful when push new commits. But It's hard to avoid making mistakes in real-life ^^

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
git checkout C8
git rebase HEAD~4
```

or

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

if you want to reorder the commits.

Comment: Thanks you for your response. But I don't think It works. Because after `git rebase HEAD~4` all commits C5, C6, C7 will be lost. Actually `git rebase HEAD~4` and `git rebase HEAD~2` (in my Step 2) will  lead to the same result!

Comment: @hungdoan: That is strange, I tested it here and it seems to work. I did not alter anything in my C4 merge commit though, except the merge itself, so it ended up throwing C4 away.